How I avoid ',' in y axis label in VegaLite?
I am trying to creating a chart in VegaLite. I have a specific requirement for y axis label I did not want to display ',' in y axiss value label.
For example -  15,000 (in vegalite showing) but I required 15000
Issue -
Editor Link
How can I achieve this in VegaLite?

I would argue that keeping the thousands separator better UX and makes the numbers easier to read.

@phuzi requirements do be like that sometimes

@DustInComp true, but pushing back is also a valid course of action here if not already done so.

I would imagine that 15k is the best option of all, which is ~s

Adding config following the docs seems to do the trick.
{
  "config": { 
    "axisLeft": {
      "format": "d"
    }
  }
}

Updated Sandbox
#Format Configuration mentions it uses D3 Format so have a look at that if you want to customize the number labels further.
